# Генераторы списков. Передать параметр в lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x: i * x for i in range(4)]

print [m(2) for m in multipliers()]
```

вызывает ошибку синтаксиса.
Как это исправить?

Comment: текст ошибки добавьте - вам помогут быстрее

Comment: print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])

Comment: print без скобок работал только во втором питоне. Но в третьем питоне принт из оператора стал простой функцией, и скобки теперь обязательны.

Comment: В вопросе указан тег python-3.x, но синтаксис вызова print явно говорит, что это python 2.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Это python 3, да скобки нужны

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме прочего, `i` нужно передать в лямбду в виде значения по умолчанию, иначе `i` внутри лямбды всегда будет равна 3

```py
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x, i=i: i * x for i in range(4)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

либо можно завернуть одну лямбду в другую, и применить все это к `i`

```py
    return [(lambda i: lambda x: i * x)(i) for i in range(4)]
```

Также можно воспользоваться связанным методом `__mul__` объекта `i`

```py
def multipliers():
    return [i.__mul__ for i in range(4)]
```

или частично примененным оператором `mul`

```py
from functools import partial
from operator import mul

def multipliers():
    return [partial(mul, i) for i in range(4)]
```

А еще с помощью библиотеки [fn](https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py) можно создавать вот такие элегантные анонимные функции в стиле `Scala`.

```py
from fn import _

def multipliers():
    return [i * _ for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Так нужно добавит скобки для print...

```
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x: i * x for i in range(4)]

print ([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код неоптимален, вы делаете генератор внутри которого каждый раз происходит переопределение лямбда-функции. Это то же самое, что и открывать файл внутри цикла для того чтобы дописать в него еще одну строку, а потом закрывать. Лучше вынести открытие файла за цикл и закрыть уже после выполнения.

Правильный ответ на эту задачу — это вынести определение лямбда-функции за цикл.

```py
def multipliers():
    l = lambda x: x*x
    return [l(i) for i in range(4)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

Кроме того, мне кажется, что в условии содержится ошибка и вам нет необходимости использовать функцию в данном месте:

```py
def multipliers_2():
    return [i*i for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только i*2, а не на i